# How to store a checkbox value into sql server database using c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm working on "Time Table Scheduling using genetic algorithm" project using C# and SQL Server..

I divided the project into 3 layers data access layer, business layer, and interfaces.

Data access layer contains:

- constructor to initialize the connection object
- method to open the connection
- method to read data from database
- method to insert, update, and delete data from database

For example:

```
//Method to insert , update ,delete data from database
public void ExecuteCommand(string stored_procedure, SqlParameter[] param)
{
            SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand();
            sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            sqlcmd.CommandText = stored_procedure;
            sqlcmd.Connection = sqlconnection;

            if (param != null)
            {
                sqlcmd.Parameters.AddRange(param);
            }
            sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

The business layer contains class for each form

For example: `ADD_COURSE.CLS` for "Add COURSE"

```
class CLS_ADD_COURSE
{
        public void ADD_COURSE(string DESC_COURSE, int TERM, bool LAB, bool Specialized)
        {
            DAL.DataAccessLayer DAL = new DAL.DataAccessLayer();
            DAL.Open();
            SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[4];

            param[0] = new SqlParameter("@DESC_COURSE", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
            param[0].Value = DESC_COURSE;

            param[1] = new SqlParameter("@TERM", SqlDbType.Int);
            param[1].Value = TERM;

            param[2] = new SqlParameter("@LAB", SqlDbType.Bit);
            param[2].Value = LAB;

            param[3] = new SqlParameter("@Specialized", SqlDbType.Bit);
            param[3].Value = Specialized;

            DAL.ExecuteCommand("ADD_COURSE", param);
            DAL.Close();
}
```

Now I want to store the data into the database so I wrote this instruction in form but it doesn't work for checkbox value

```
COURSE.ADD_COURSE(txt_COURSE_name.Text, Convert.ToInt32(TXT_COURSE_TERM.Text),Convert.ToBoolean(CHECK_LAB.Text),Convert.ToBoolean(CHECK_SP.Text));
```

So how to store a checkbox value into a SQL Server database using C#?

This my procedure:

```
create PROC [dbo].[ADD_COURSE]
   @DESC_COURSE VARCHAR(50),
   @TERM INT,
   @LAB BIT,
   @Specialized BIT
AS
   INSERT INTO [dbo].[COURSE]([DESC_COURSE], [TERM], [LAB],[Specialized ])  
   VALUES (@DESC_COURSE, @TERM, @LAB, @Specialized)
```

Comment: COURSE.ADD_COURSE(txt_COURSE_name.Text, Convert.ToInt32(TXT_COURSE_TERM.Text),CHECK_LAB.Checked,CHECK_SP.Checked); // we assume that the checkbox.ThreeState is false. see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkbox.checked%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do something like this.
here i am inserting employee into db.. see admin rights. which is a check box
and adminrights db type is bit

```
                SqlCommand Command = new SqlCommand();
                Command.Connection = MyConnection;
                Command.CommandText =
                    "Insert into Employees (ID, Name, Last_name, Username, Password, E_mail, Address, administrator_rights)"
                    + "values(@ID, @Name, @Last_name, @Username, @Password, @E_mail,Address, @admin_rights )";

            Command.Parameters.Add("@ID", 1); // some generated number
            Command.Parameters.Add("@Name", TextBoxName.Text);
            Command.Parameters.Add("@Last_name", TextBoxLastName.Text);
            Command.Parameters.Add("@Username", TextBoxUserName.Text);
            Command.Parameters.Add("@Password", TextBoxPassword.Text);
            Command.Parameters.Add("@E_mail", TextBoxEmail.Text);
            Command.Parameters.Add("@Address", TextBoxAddress.Text);
            Command.Parameters.Add("@admin_rights", CheckBoxAdminRights.Checked);

            using (MyConnection)
            {
                Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `int,tinyint, bit` to store it in database. If the the checkbox is **checked** store it as 1, if it is **unchecked** store it is  as 0. When you take the value of the checkbox you should perform same thing. If the value in the database is 1 set the checkbox to be checked.

There is possibility to store multiple values of checkbox in one database field using **bitmask** logic. But probably you don't need that in your case.

Comment: bit datatype is enough to store Boolean values (True/False/Null) , no need to waste storage of database by using int or tinyint .

Comment: @houssam if you use to store bitmask values you need int.

Comment: you are right regarding bitmask (set of flags), it is very usefull, +1 for this.